# not debuging my phone android application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-debug

I am trying to test my android app (android 2.3.3) via my karboon A1+ phone. However, I cannot get Eclipse to recognize my device on the debug config menu. My phone is recognized by my computer when I connect via the usb cable. I can access my phone via windows but not Eclipse. Also, the karboon A1+ driver has been recently updated when I updated to android 2.3.4.

The reason I am using my phone to debug is b.c the emulator keeps crashing/failing to install my app. I am running Windows Vista 32bit. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in developer mode on your phone?

This might help - [Android devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)

You would possible need to install the android drivers called ADB
This is also how to install the android driver from your SDK - [Installing Drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#WinVista)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to enable apps from 'unknown sources' and enable ADB debugging.

Without both of those you can't install and get the console output from your app, which is pretty essential.

Answer (score 0):

Those devices from small manufacturers are really tricky to get the drivers to work.

Apparently [this guy got it working](http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/574997-adb-not-showing-device.html#post4604093), it's a very hacky way, but I'll put his text:

> I downloaded Zte n721 USB driver for my mobile. ( It
>   requires speecific driver for your device. Google usb drivers works
>   for very few mobiles. ) Then I put vender ID for Zte 0x19d2 to my
>   adb_usb.inf. ( You can not save in edit but you have to use : echo
>   0x19d2 >> adb_usb.inf ( use your vendor id you can get it from net I
>   got it from mypcdrivers.com)  When you allow debugging on the mobile,
>   it works.

Apart from that the best thing is try to contact directly with your device manufacturer via this link http://www.karbonnmobiles.com/contact_us.php and demand an ADB Driver.